# Appropriate Approaches for Unsupervised Textual Classification

Tags: machine-learning, python, r, unsupervised-learning

Let's say I take 1000 dissertations from a variety of different fields, and thereafter extract the top 100 words from each dissertation. What would be the best approach to categorize them into STEM/non-STEM without having a sample of STEM/non-STEM dissertations to compare? Is there an R package that will sort them based on shared language without pre-tagging words (so a bit different from semantic or sentiment analysis)?

Presumably they will all share a core vocabulary, and there will be some overlap here and there, but presuming we can know from the top 100 words, what tools would assist in that? For this type of work, I've seen far more examples of supervised learning, but I'm much more interested in seeing how they could possibly be grouped, even if the end result isn't a division into majors per se.

The setup/fact that they're dissertations/theses doesn't matter. A similar idea could be to take two playwrights and analyze their plays to see if they're correctly sorted by authorship. What approach should I be taking here?

Comment: In a pretrained word2vec, would the mean sum distance of top100 from STEM token be a good way to measure this?

Comment: @hH1sG0n3 Oh, this looks useful! I haven't used this yet, thanks!